# Terraform OCI - 403 Please go to your home region

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-provider-oci

I currently have a terraform code to create some basic infrastructure on oracle and it works if I pass the region "us-sanjose-1" ", but when I change to the region" us-ashburn-1 "it generates the following error:

```
Error: 403-NotAllowed
Provider version: 4.57.0, released on 2021-12-15. This provider is 1 version (s) old.
Service: Identity Compartment
Error Message: Please go to your home region SJC to execute CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE operations.
OPC request ID: 1013eb7e50e7ad8be4fc9b9ebd74f9b1 / 541F5669434AC8A6DBA4E4066E22E9FD / AF07524AE4A50B693AC5426DC5981345
Suggestion: Please retry or contact support for help with service: Identity Compartment
```

From OCI web administration console i can create resources for the two regions whithout errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected from Identity service that Compartment can only be created in your home region (us-sanjose-1). Note that Compartments are tenancy-wide, across regions. When you create a compartment, it is available in every region that your tenancy is subscribed to. You can get a cross-region view of your resources in a specific compartment with the tenancy explorer.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/managingcompartments.htm

Comment: What about policies? I've run into the exact same issue trying to create a policy, it looks like they're also region specific?